# When do bucket names expire and get released?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I created a bucket in a project. I subsequently deleted that project, so its bucket should be deleted along with it.

Now I'm attempting to make a bucket with the same name in another project, but I get the error:

"This bucket name is already in use. Bucket names must be globally unique. Try another name."

It's been over 12 hours. Documentation suggests that bucket IDs are supposed to get released if they are no longer in use. Will that bucket ID ever become available again?

Comment: For future reference, if you delete a bucket directly instead of deleting the project to which it belongs, I believe that the bucket name near-instantly becomes available for reclamation.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough, that is not the case. I am having the same problem, and I deleted the bucket. Only after noticing that I could not create a new bucket with that name, did I delete the project (which did not help).

Answer (score 1):

From [the support documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en):

> Shutting down a project stops all billing and traffic serving, shuts
>   down any Google Cloud Platform App Engine applications, and terminates
>   all Compute Engine instances. All project data associated with Google
>   Cloud and Google APIs services becomes inaccessible.
>
> After a 7-day waiting period, the project and associated data are
>   permanently deleted from the console.
>
> Note that after the 7-day waiting period ends, the time it takes to
>   completely delete a project may vary. For example, if a project has
>   billing set up, it might not be completely deleted until the current
>   billing cycle ends, you receive the next bill, and your account is
>   successfully charged. Additionally, the number and types of services
>   in use may also affect when the system permanently deletes a project.

Comment: Well, it's been 7 days and the bucket id is still in use. Maybe someone else grabbed it? Sad ;(

Comment: Keep in mind, as it says up above, the time it takes after 7 days can vary, so I would keep trying.

Comment: At this point I actually suspect there might be a bug and my bucket name wasn't released because of some race condition. I deleted the project while there was a transfer still pending in the bucket, so maybe that's related to why it's not available again. I don't have a support contract, but is there any way I could shoot a quick e-mail to someone at Google to check for me? I'm kevin@z.cash.